# Android Maps Point Clustering

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview, markerclusterer

Is there any code for Point Clustering in android? How can i load thousand pinpoint without having performance issues?

Comment: it's not a question. As i stated it's a faq .. sort of tutorial. "Saw that there was nothing out for the community so i would like to share"

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Though it's encouraged to post informative knowledge, these kind of posts should stick with SOs Q&A format. This means you should formulate a question and answer it. See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You can also accept your own answers, theres even a badge for that. I'll upvote this to compensate for the downvotes - they're a bit harsh imho.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Last night i got into PointClustering on Android MapView. Saw that there was nothing out for the community so i would like to share.

Groups the geopoints if the projection of them in the mapView is too close. Also renders only the visible poins.

**UPDATE**

**Code reworked from scrach.**

**Now available at [GitHub](https://github.com/weakwire/AndroidMapCluster)**

1. Code Reworked from scratch
2. Used GVM clustering algorithm (pretty fast but doesn't position clustered point as good as mine)
3. Soon to add previous clustering algorithm too

[image]

Comment: I think there are a few things missing in your post, such as where is `public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)` supposed to go?

Comment: And what does OverlayItemExtended's getName() returns? Your post would be greatly improved if you provided the whole source

Comment: I edited the answer based on your suggestion. getName() is the getTitle() of the OverlayItem ,or what the point should render as a name to the map.

Comment: I cannot post the entire code as it's a work in progress of a current inDevelopment project.

Comment: thx for sharing this. i worked through the provided code and i think i figured most of it out. But as pandre already asked: could you also provide the code for the PointCluster Class? Does it only contain a static getOverLayItemDistance-Method? @pandre: The code for the draw() Method belongs within the class that is extending ItemizedOverlay. It overrides its draw-method. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327733/it-is-possible-to-remove-the-shadow-of-the-icons-items-on-a-googlemap

Comment: ty totally forgot it. i updated it with the PointCluster class.

Comment: @weakwire did you finish the class? I copied your source and edited to fix the missing parts, but still not working.

Comment: what is not working?The class is finished. I'll propably post the whole scr when the project i'm working on is finished. Not now.

Comment: @weakwire when I place your code inside a file Eclipse show multitude of errors, great work though, Hope to see it complete soon. :)

Comment: putting this in github would be nice

Comment: this code can easily be speeded up by not creating the paint objects inside onDraw() (and especially not inside a loop inside onDraw). A quick win!

Comment: you are right. as i mentioned "Sorry for the code is not finished yet but you get the idea." but ty for the comment you are absolutely right

Comment: Where's this method itemizedOverlay.removeAllOverlays() ? Anyone succeeded in reordering/sorting everything? I'm lost.

Comment: added removePointsButMe method. All the code is there. I will post the code on a working project to gidhub / google code in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for this. Another question thought, could you explain what is overlay.isMe? And where is the addOverlayItem method?

Comment: It seems your code actually works, since you provide screenshots, so can't you share the whole project ? It's so messy to make copy paste from here directly...

Answer (score 4):

I have reworked in the above code and controlled the no of overlay icon in the map view and separated the group and single point.

My Code:

### MMapView.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.impiger.maphighlight.R;

//Reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering

public class MMapView extends MapView {

    private static final String TAG = MMapView.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int MAX_VISIBLE_POINTS = 1;
    private PMapViewOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    private List<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    private BitmapDrawable drawable;
    private Context context;
    private Drawable emptyDrawable;
    private int count;
    private int oldZoomLevel = -1;
    ArrayList<OverlayItemExtended> mOverlays;

    public MMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        mapOverlays = getOverlays();
        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.blue_65));
        itemizedOverlay = new PMapViewOverlay(drawable, context);
        emptyDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.marker);
        mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItemExtended>();
        init();
    }

    private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
        return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
    }

    private void init(){
        putPoint(11, 77, true);
        putPoint(11.5, 76.6, false);
        putPoint(10.98383, 77.32112, false);
        putPoint(10, 77, false);
        putPoint(11, 78, false);
        putPoint(11, 77.5, false);
        putPoint(10.5, 77, false);
        putPoint(12, 77, false);
        putPoint(11.77, 77.11, false);
        putPoint(12.1, 78.33, false);
        putPoint(11.83, 77.293, false);
        putPoint(11.12, 77, false);
        putPoint(11.13, 77, false);
        putPoint(11.14, 77, false);
        putPoint(11.15, 77, false);
        putPoint(11.12, 77.2, false);
        putPoint(11.13, 77.34, false);
        putPoint(11.14, 77.4, false);
        putPoint(11.15, 77.1977, false);
        putPoint(11.347373, 77.5627783, true);
        putPoint(11.53454, 76.696645, false);
        putPoint(10.19282, 77.847373, false);
        putPoint(10.4728, 76.39388, false);
        putPoint(11.4563, 78, false);
        putPoint(11.73663, 77.5927, false);
        putPoint(10.5674, 77.6762, false);
        putPoint(12.02882, 77.672782, false);
        putPoint(11.7767876, 77.1123423, false);
        putPoint(12.18332, 78.33, false);
        putPoint(11.8393883, 77.293938783, false);
        putPoint(11.388323, 77.9478723, false);
        putPoint(11.1345645, 77.97723, false);
        putPoint(11.1423423, 77.73774, false);
        putPoint(11.1552, 77.793783, false);
        putPoint(11.127895434, 77.2944554, false);
        putPoint(11.13232345, 77.342234, false);
        putPoint(11.14456573, 77.4, false);
        putPoint(11.159765, 77.1977, false);
    }


    public void putPoint(double lat, double lon, boolean isMyPosition) {
        int latitude = (int) (lat * 1E6);
        int longitude = (int) (lon * 1E6);
        GeoPoint geo = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        geo = getPoint(lat, lon);

        /*
         * Remove doubles
         */
        Boolean alreadyExists = false;
        for (GeoPoint item : geoPoints) {
            if (item.getLatitudeE6() == geo.getLatitudeE6()
                    && item.getLongitudeE6() == geo.getLongitudeE6()) {
                alreadyExists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!alreadyExists) {
            geoPoints.add(geo);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Place the overlays
     */
    public void placeOverlays() {
        itemizedOverlay.removeAllOverlays();
        getOverlays().clear();
        mapOverlays.clear();
        mOverlays.clear();
        int i = 1;
        for (GeoPoint item : geoPoints) {
            OverlayItemExtended overlayitem = new OverlayItemExtended(item,
                    "title "+i, "snippet");
            // Here is where the magic happens
            addOverlayItemClustered(overlayitem, this,
                    geoPoints.size());
            i++;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<mOverlays.size();j++){
            OverlayItemExtended overlayItem = mOverlays.get(j);
            if(overlayItem.isMaster){
                if(overlayItem.slaves.size() > 0){
                    itemizedOverlay = new PMapViewOverlay(drawable, context);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
                }else{
                    itemizedOverlay = new PMapViewOverlay(emptyDrawable, context);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
                }
                mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Update the points at panned / zoom etc
     */
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        if (getZoomLevel() != oldZoomLevel) {
            placeOverlays();
        }
        oldZoomLevel = getZoomLevel();
    }

    public void addOverlayItemClustered(OverlayItemExtended thisOverlay,
            MapView mapView, int totalPoints) {
        for (OverlayItemExtended otherOverlay : mOverlays) {
            /*
             * Thresshold for the clustering
             */
            /*
             * Zoom level >15 don't cluster If less than Max_Visible_points
             * don't cluster
             */
            if (mapView.getZoomLevel() >= 14
                    || (MAX_VISIBLE_POINTS > totalPoints)
                    && PointCluster.getOverLayItemDistance(thisOverlay,
                            otherOverlay, mapView) > 60) {
                mOverlays.add(thisOverlay);
                return;
            }
            if (PointCluster.getOverLayItemDistance(thisOverlay, otherOverlay,
                    mapView) < 90 && !thisOverlay.isClustered) {
                // Here is where the clustering actually happens
                if (otherOverlay.isMaster) {
                    thisOverlay.isMaster = false;
                    // otherOverlay.isMaster = false;
                    thisOverlay.isClustered = true;
                    otherOverlay.isClustered = true;
                    otherOverlay.slaves.push(thisOverlay);
                    thisOverlay.parent = otherOverlay;
                } else if (PointCluster.getOverLayItemDistance(thisOverlay,
                        otherOverlay.parent, mapView) < 90
                        && otherOverlay.isClustered) {
                    thisOverlay.isMaster = false;
                    thisOverlay.isClustered = true;
                    thisOverlay.parent = otherOverlay.parent;
                    otherOverlay.parent.slaves.push(thisOverlay);
                }
            }
        }
        mOverlays.add(thisOverlay);
    }
}
```

### OverlayItemExtended.java

```
import java.util.Stack;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class OverlayItemExtended extends OverlayItem {

    public boolean isClustered = false;
    public boolean isMaster = true;
    public boolean isMe = false;
    public OverlayItemExtended parent;
    public Stack<OverlayItemExtended> slaves = new Stack<OverlayItemExtended>();

    public OverlayItemExtended(GeoPoint point, String title, String snippet) {
        super(point, title, snippet);
    }
}
```

### PMapViewOverlay.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class PMapViewOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private static final String TAG = PMapViewOverlay.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<OverlayItemExtended> mOverlays;

    public PMapViewOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.context = context;
        mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItemExtended>();

        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItemExtended createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItemExtended overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void removeAllOverlays() {
        mOverlays.clear();
        populate();
    }

    public void removePointsButMe() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mOverlays.size(); i++) {
            OverlayItemExtended overlay = mOverlays.get(i);
            if (overlay.isMe) {
                mOverlays.clear();
                addOverlayItem(overlay);
                break;
            }
        }
        populate();
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        // cycle through all overlays
        for (int index = 0; index < mOverlays.size(); index++) {
            OverlayItemExtended item = mOverlays.get(index);

            // Converts lat/lng-Point to coordinates on the screen
            GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();
            Point ptScreenCoord = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, ptScreenCoord);

            if (item.isMaster) {
                if (item.slaves.size() > 0) {
                    canvas.drawText(item.slaves.size() + 1 + "",
                            ptScreenCoord.x, ptScreenCoord.y - 13, paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItemExtended item = mOverlays.get(index);
        if (item.isMaster) {
            if (item.slaves.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You tapped item " + item.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        return super.onTap(index);
    }
}
```

I didn't change any code in PointCluster.java.

I hope this will help somebody.[image]

Comment: I didn't change any code in PointCluster.java?
Where is PointCluster.java? Can you post it?

Comment: @Shrikant: You can find the PointCluster http://code.google.com/p/posit-mobile/issues/attachmentText?id=341&aid=3410006001&name=PointCluster.java&token=LcULxfBdvuDxXZ0ozbCo1_czN1o%3A1335505698432

Answer (score 2):

Google's [Android Map Utils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/) has a solution for this: [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering).

**Add dependency**

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

**Make your own ClusterItem**

```
class MyItem(
        private val position: LatLng,
        val title: String,
        private val snippet: String
) : ClusterItem {
    override fun getPosition() = position
    override fun getTitle() = title
    override fun getSnippet() = snippet
}
```

**Setting up the cluster manager and adding items**

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    val clusterManager = ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, googleMap)
    googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)

    clusterManager.addItem(MyItem(LatLng(51.51, -0.12), "title", "snippet"))
}
```

That's it! Items are now shown as follows:

[image: screenshot Marker Clustering Utility in action]

**Customizing the icon**

In order to customize the icon, add `val icon: BitmapDescriptor` to your ClusterItem and change the renderer of the cluster manager:

```
    clusterManager.renderer = object : DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem>(this, googleMap, clusterManager) {
        override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: MyItem, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) {
            markerOptions.icon(item.icon)
        }
    }
```

**Making items clickable**

As a rule of thumb, any interaction with markers should go through the cluster manager instead. The same applies to making items clickable.

```
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
    clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on item ${it.title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        true
    }
```

Similarly, you can call `googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager)` and `clusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener` to handle clicks on the info window.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice sample for it. Check it here: http://code.google.com/p/android-playground-erdao/source/browse/trunk/SampleClusterMap/?r=226

Answer (score 1):

There is a pull request on github for the Polaris library (https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris) which adds clustering:

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris/pull/20

https://github.com/damianflannery/Polaris/tree/clustering

Answer (score 0):

There also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11577058/673206) which only requires you override the draw method of your Overlay. It divides your mapView into sections, so it's a bit less sophisticated. But at least it worked.

Answer (score 0):

FOR ANDROID V2 HERE GOES CLUSTERING CODE

Hi All

I looked at various libraries and found them so complexx could'nt understand a word so i decided to make my own clutering algo
Here goes my code in java

```
static int OFFSET = 268435456;
static double RADIUS = 85445659.4471;
static double pi = 3.1444;

public static double lonToX(double lon) {
        return Math.round(OFFSET + RADIUS * lon * pi / 180);
    }

    public static double latToY(double lat) {
        return Math.round(OFFSET
                - RADIUS
                * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(lat * pi / 180))
                        / (1 - Math.sin(lat * pi / 180))) / 2);
    }

    public static int pixelDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
            double lon2, int zoom) {
        double x1 = lonToX(lon1);
        double y1 = latToY(lat1);

        double x2 = lonToX(lon2);
        double y2 = latToY(lat2);

        return (int) (Math
                .sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2))) >> (21 - zoom);
    }

    static ArrayList<Cluster> cluster(ArrayList<Marker> markers, int zoom) {

        ArrayList<Cluster> clusterList = new ArrayList<Cluster>();

        ArrayList<Marker> originalListCopy = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        for (Marker marker : markers) {
            originalListCopy.add(marker);
        }

        /* Loop until all markers have been compared. */
        for (int i = 0; i < originalListCopy.size();) {

            /* Compare against all markers which are left. */

            ArrayList<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < markers.size();) {
                int pixelDistance = pixelDistance(markers.get(i).getLatitude(),
                        markers.get(i).getLongitude(), markers.get(j)
                                .getLatitude(), markers.get(j).getLongitude(),
                        zoom);

                if (pixelDistance < 40) {

                    markerList.add(markers.get(i));
                    markerList.add(markers.get(j));

                    markers.remove(j);

                    originalListCopy.remove(j);
                    j = i + 1;
                } else {
                    j++;
                }

            }

            if (markerList.size() > 0) {
                Cluster cluster = new Cluster(clusterList.size(), markerList,
                        markerList.size() + 1, originalListCopy.get(i)
                                .getLatitude(), originalListCopy.get(i)
                                .getLongitude());
                clusterList.add(cluster);
                originalListCopy.remove(i);
                markers.remove(i);
                i = 0;

            } else {
                i++;
            }

            /* If a marker has been added to cluster, add also the one */
            /* we were comparing to and remove the original from array. */

        }
        return clusterList;
    }
```

Just pass in your array list here containing latitude and longitude
then to display clusters
here goes the function

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<FlatDetails> flatDetailsList) {

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        originalListCopy = new ArrayList<FlatDetails>();
        ArrayList<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        for (FlatDetails detailList : flatDetailsList) {

            markersList.add(new Marker(detailList.getLatitude(), detailList
                    .getLongitude(), detailList.getApartmentTypeString()));

            originalListCopy.add(detailList);

            builder.include(new LatLng(detailList.getLatitude(), detailList
                    .getLongitude()));

        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

        googleMap.moveCamera(cu);

        ArrayList<Cluster> clusterList = Utils.cluster(markersList,
                (int) googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);

        // Removes all markers, overlays, and polylines from the map.
        googleMap.clear();

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(previousZoomLevel),
                2000, null);

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(point) //
                // setcenter
                .radius(3000) // set radius in meters
                .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) // default
                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE).strokeWidth(5);

        googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

        for (Marker detail : markersList) {

            if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("1 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk1)));
            } else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("2 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk_2)));

            }

            else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("3 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk_3)));

            } else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("2.5 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk2)));

            } else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("4 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk_4)));

            } else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("5 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk5)));

            } else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("5+ BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk_5)));

            }

            else if (detail.getBhkTypeString().equalsIgnoreCase("2 BHK")) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(detail.getLatitude(), detail
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(""))
                        .title("Flat" + flatDetailsList.indexOf(detail))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromResource(R.drawable.bhk_2)));

            }
        }

        for (Cluster cluster : clusterList) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inMutable = true;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.cluster_marker, options);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            paint.setTextSize(30);

            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(cluster.getMarkerList().size()), 10,
                    40, paint);

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(cluster.getClusterLatitude(), cluster
                                    .getClusterLongitude()))
                    .snippet(String.valueOf(cluster.getMarkerList().size()))
                    .title("Cluster")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));

        }

    }
```

ANY QUESTIONS OR DOUBTS PLEASE ASK WILL CLEAR THEM ALL ...........THANKS