# Index Out of Bounds suddenly for some users in Mapview ANDROID

Tags: android, android-mapview, indexoutofboundsexception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.preLoad(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:234)
at com.google.android.maps.MapController.animateTo(MapController.java:225)
```

Code has been working beautifully for months, now suddenly I am getting reports of the following bug.  The API KEY is correct, and works for me so I don't think that's it.. but I suppose I could resubmit the MD5 to Google, but fear that will change the KEY and break everyone who hasn't upgraded.

I don't know why this is happening, as its not in code that I control, I do call an aminate to user location but validate that the location is not null before I call it, so I don't think that's it.. Is it possible that UserLocation can exist but have invalid values?  API says it should be NULL if it hasn't been set yet, but I've been burned before by manufacturers who don't follow the API properly.

I Really wish The Android Marketplace would include device information with bug reports.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is supposedly causing the crash?

Comment: I get this message too only from devices running 4.0.4.  The Galaxy Nexus and the Galaxy SIII.  Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you fix it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are exactly looking for, b'coz you didn't provide any code..
but i am facing the same problem in zoom in/out ,strong text and i am finally got the answer in Android Cluster Mapping. 
look for it ..it might help you.

one of the i followed: 
[Android Maps Point Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering)