# android google map collecting markers together

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

i have a map with multiple markers on it.

 it is now rare that some of the markers will be super close to each other, and then they override each other that only one marker will be seeing.

how can i collect a bunch of markers to one marker with a number (of the bunch markers) on it ?

for now i've just made a recursion method which moves the marker if its too close to other marker, but that's not a good solution for lost of markers.

Thanks !

Comment: You looking for something like this?  http://www.redfin.com/homes-for-sale#!disp_mode=M&lat=33.48529862405761&long=-96.38102036828343&market=dallas&sf=1,2&v=8&zoomLevel=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Google Maps Marker Clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html).

Comment: Looks like it's not as easy for Android.  Check this out...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering