# Placing thousands of pins on google map in android app

Tags: javascript, android, algorithm, maps, markerclusterer

I'm working with my programmers and have an issue that we're trying to find a simple / opensource solution to as i'm sure others have come across the same issue before...

In simple terms we're trying to place thousands of pins on a google map within an android application....

We managed to solve the problem of placing thousands of pins on a google map within xcode by using a clustering algorithm that placed them in clusters and gave the number of pins in a particular area, then as you zoom in , the pins specifically appear in their locations.

However, when trying to use this same algorithm within the android space, we're finding it slow and unstable, with the application crashing and becoming unusable.

clearly just trying to populate all the pin locations on the map is not the solution, but another solution along the lines of clustering or loading pins when at different zoom levels....if you can help by directing me to what someone else has done to solve this problem or suggest a solution, I would be very grateful,

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed with regards to what your 'clustering algorithm' is and what is causing the Android app to crash.

Comment: Are you using Google's MarkerManager?

Comment: This is not [tag:cluster-analysis] (so I removed the tag, and replaced it with [tag:markerclusterer]). Read it up on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this answer [AndroidMapCluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7447998/1050058) and another project [SampleClusterMapActivity](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground-erdao/source/browse/trunk/SampleClusterMap/src/com/erdao/android/SampleClusterMap/SampleClusterMapActivity.java?r=226)