# Android Google map having more than a thousand markers?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have a mapview in my application. And I have to show more than 1,000 overlays on a map. 
And I have a list which is containing these places. So, do I have to create 1,000 overlay objects by iterating over the items in the list? And can anyone give me an efficient way to do this?

Comment: see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994800/displaying-multiple-markers-on-google-map

Comment: Possible [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12483065/1050058). Check my answer for `Map Clustering`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the Sanket is doing it the points are populated after every single point is added, this tends to lag out. A more effiecent way can be done like this:

What is happening is that you are populating the MapView everytime you add a GeoPoint. Try adding this to your code:

after you have looped through the GeoPoints place this code

```
itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
```

and change you itemizedOverlay to look like this:

```
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
m_overlays.add(overlay);
    }
public void populateNow()
{
populate(); 
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
return m_overlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
return m_overlays.size();
}
```

Comment: Hello. i am iterating the list in anther thread. now where to call the populateNow method on itemizedOveray

Answer (score 0):

for this you don't have to make 1000 overlay.. just add overlay in itemizedoverlay and add this itemizedoverlay in mapoverlay and populate overlay before adding new itemizedoverlay..

```
try
         {
         point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getLatitude()) * 1e6),(int) (Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).getLongitude()) * 1e6));
         overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, list.get(i).getLocationName()+"_@_"+list.get(i).getLatitude()+"_@_"+list.get(i).getLongitude()+"_@_yes", list.get(i).getAddress());
         itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
         itemizedoverlay.populateOverlay();
                 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Log.v("log",""+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show only visible area markers and invisible area markers hide by below code;

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
@Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
         LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

         for (Marker marker : markerArrayList) {
             if (bounds.contains(marker.getPosition())) {
                   marker.setVisible(true);
             } else {
                   marker.setVisible(false);
             }
        }
      }
   });
```