# Make a cluster with OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid, markerclusterer

I already saw some things on StackOverflow about that problem, but none of them were about Osmdroid, but Google Maps. Because it's not the same, a lot of methods from the MapView (Google Maps) are not in the MapView (OSMdroid). I tried to change it somehow, but it still don't work.

Here's the link i'm talking about : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering)

Comment: Have you considered taking Android Maps Extensions or Clusterkraf open source clustering libraries and making them work with OSMdroid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878892/cluster-markers-with-osmdroid

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample, commented code.

```
// create and set up a clusterer
final RadiusMarkerClusterer clusterer = new RadiusMarkerClusterer(context);
clusterer.setIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cluster));
clusterer.setRadius(85);
clusterer.mTextAnchorU = 0.70f;
clusterer.mTextAnchorV = 0.27f;
clusterer.getTextPaint().setTextSize(14.0f);

Drawable markerDrawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

// for each entry, create and set up a marker
for (MarkerInfo info : markerData) {
    Marker mr = new Marker(mapView);
    mr.setPosition(new GeoPoint(markerData.lat, markerData.lng));
    mr.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
    mr.setTitle(markerData.title);
    mr.setIcon(markerDrawable);
    clusterer.add(mr);
}

// replace overlays
final List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
overlays.clear();
overlays.add(clusterer);
```

Comment: i think overlays.add(clusterer); should be out of the loop not in !

Comment: @BADEREDDINEQODIA, I don't remember why I've done this way seven years ago, but yes, looks like it should. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

below link can help you to implement RadiusMarkerClusterer in osm android=>

```
https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/tree/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering
```

after that you can use below code =>

```
        RadiusMarkerClusterer clusterer = new RadiusMarkerClusterer(this);
        clusterer.setIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), org.osmdroid.bonuspack.R.drawable.marker_cluster));


        for (Model model: list) {
            Marker mr = new Marker(mMapView);
            mr.setPosition(new GeoPoint(model.getLat(), model.getLng()));
            clusterer.add(mr);
        }

        // replace overlays
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(clusterer);
```