# Cluster markers with osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am new to `osmdroid`. I am using offline maps using `mbtiles`. I am using too many markers on the map that make my map very slow. I read it some where that clustering would be helpful but i am not getting any useful example of how to make cluster marker in `osmdroid`.
please help.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: i did not find it :-(

Comment: Not yet? .————.

Answer (score 6):

Now there is a ready-to-use solution: in OSMBonusPack (an add-on to osmdroid), there is a MarkerClusterer.

The tutorial is here: http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_3

Comment: MKer, Do you know any Android projects with a stable implementation of markers clustering with the OSMDROID library. (gradle not eclipse) If the answer is yes, do you have any source code access links?

Comment: Yes: the link is provided in the answer just above!