# Detecting zoom changes at MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I have an Android app with a MapView, and zoom controls have been implemented. But I want to detect when the zoom level has changed, so I can do certain things when that happens. Is there any listener to do that? Any example?

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2013443/593709)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a little bit of research, I found this site:

http://pa.rezendi.com/2010/03/responding-to-zooms-and-pans-in.html

Specifically, this code:

```
int oldZoomLevel=-1;

public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
  if (getZoomLevel() != oldZoomLevel) {
   //do your thing
   oldZoomLevel = getZoomLevel();
  }
}
```

Would seem to do more or less what you want.

Edit:

In other words, you can solve this by subclassing the mapview, and override the dispatchDraw.