# Android Google Map show markers on zoom change

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

Guys I have to show markers on google maps with zoom.When user zoom in or zoom out  markers will be visible covering the map area which is on the screen.How can I do this using Android google map?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013443/on-zoom-event-for-google-maps-on-android

Comment: So you want to add markers whenever you zoom in or out?

Comment: @Evan yes I want this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so you can use a CameraChangeListener:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Marker> courseMarkers = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();
//all your visible markers
ArrayList<Item> yourMarkerList = new ArrayList<Item>();
//method to add all your markers with unique ids
addItemsToMap(); //first call to initially show the markers you want

googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

private float currentZoom = -1; //keep track of your current zoom level

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition camera) {
    if (camera.zoom != currentZoom){
        currentZoom = camera.zoom;
        //here you will then check your markers
        addItemsToMap(yourMarkerList);
    }
}
});
```

You will need a class Item that has a variable for a unique int id and a MarkerOptions

```
private void addItemsToMap(List<Item> items)
{
if(this.mMap != null)
{
    //This is the current user-viewable region of the map
    LatLngBounds bounds = this.mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

    //Loop through all the items that are available to be placed on the map
    for(Item m : item) 
    {

        //If the item is within the the bounds of the screen
        if(bounds.contains(item.getMarker().getPosition()))
        {
            //If the item isn't already being displayed
            if(!courseMarkers.containsKey(item.getId()))
            {
                //Add the Marker to the Map and keep track of it with the HashMap
                //getMarkerForItem just returns a MarkerOptions object
                this.courseMarkers.put(item.getId(), this.googleMap.addMarker(item.getMarker())); //getmarkerforitem
            }
        }

        //If the marker is off screen
        else
        {
            //If the course was previously on screen
            if(courseMarkers.containsKey(item.getId()))
            {
                //1. Remove the Marker from the GoogleMap
                courseMarkers.get(item.getId()).remove();

                //2. Remove the reference to the Marker from the HashMap
                courseMarkers.remove(item.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This should do it

Comment: I have already done this in my code.Now I need help in markers I have a list of points which I need to show/hide on zoom in and zoom out.how can I do that?

Comment: so do you want to hide certain markers when they are offscreen?

Comment: yes I want this and show certain markers when they onscreen

Comment: @Even Thank You so much.What is the courserMarkers here?

Comment: Look at the top bit of code, it's a HashMap, a data structure that links a key to an Object

Comment: If you've fixed your problem it would be nice to accept an answer :)

Comment: @Even Thank You so much for ur support.Your answer was great but there is little problem which i need to resolve as soon as i done I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58962/discussion-between-robin-royal-and-evan).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void pointToPosition(LatLng position) {
    //Build camera position
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(position)
            .zoom(15).build();
    //Zoom in and animate the camera.
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```