# my location button event click on titanium map v3

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, titanium

Is there a way to get the click on the my location button in a map in titanium? It is possible to get the "regionchanged" event when te user changes the maps position like zoom or something else. But how can I get the click on the my location button?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onMyLocationButtonClick()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener) this can be used to know when the user has clicked the button and returns `true` if the listener has consumed the event. False otherwise. The default behavior is for the camera move such that it is centered on the user location.

```
//add location button click listener
map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener(){
@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
{
//TODO: Any custom actions
return false;
}
});
```

You can also [`regionchanged`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Google_Maps_v2_for_Android) event. This event fires when the user either changes the zoom level or pans the Map View. The event returns the new latitude and longitude coordinates as well as delta values.

```
mapview.addEventListener('regionchanged', function(e){
Ti.API.info(e.type);
Ti.API.info(e.latitude + "," + e.longitude);
});
```

Here's a related SO ticket, discuss about regionchanged events: [On zoom event for google maps on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013443/on-zoom-event-for-google-maps-on-android)